# Where did my relational attributes go?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, linq-to-entities, navigation-properties

I have a db that has the following tables (roughly):

Task

- taskId

Step

- stepId

TaskStep

- stepId
- taskId
- sortOrder

When converting the db into EF I cannot find out how to access sortOrder. Since TaskStep is a relation between task and step it turns it into a navigation property. How do you access attributes of a navigation property?

I am attempting to do the following in my api:

```
// GET api/task/GetSteps/<id>
    public IEnumerable<Step> GetSteps(int id)
    {

        //get the steps for the task
        var steps = from step in db.iPAWS_Step
                    where step.iPAWS_Task.Any(x => x.taskId == id)
                    select new Step
                    {
                        stepId = step.stepId,
                        text = step.text,
                        video = step.video,
                        audio = step.audio,
                        sortOrder = step.sortOrder // step.sortOrder does not exist
                    };

        //return the steps
        return steps;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to create new steps instead of just returning the ones from your LINQ query?

Comment: How would I do that? and would that return the sortOrder?

Comment: `var steps = db.iPAWS_Step.Where(x => x.taskId == id);` I'm not sure where your sort order is, so this code is basically doing what you're already doing, but more efficiently since you don't create new Step objects.

Comment: Whenever I would try and return without using a custom defined class I receive a serialization error. Returning via a custom class fixed this issue.
for example:

    `//get the steps for the task
            var steps = from step in db.iPAWS_Step
                        where step.iPAWS_Task.Any(x => x.taskId == id)
                        select step;`

results in: The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

Comment: Is there an inner exception? What happens if you wrap your query in parentheses and then call .ToList on the results?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Mason - i still receive the error. The inner exception is: An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Self referencing loop detected with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.iPAWS_Step_902FEA36D895DE8D71206EBC7F7F8E78CB61A29106B6DFB7D233A9FE36D7DB6B'. Path '[0].iPAWS_Step1[0].iPAWS_Step2' These are navigation properties for the recursive relationship of a step

John - Thank you, I was unaware of this.